# Download a pdf file using https path in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, download

I have an ajax call to the controller which returns in success block as a path to the pdf file which something looks like this `www. bts.abcd.com/ReportPdf/BH00118051710501_1_1.pdf`, now i want to write some code in javascript that would download this file.
I have tried various methods like `winodw.location.href="path"` but this only opens the file in new window not downloading it.
here's my code.

`

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
     url: "/Reporting/ReportAPI",
     data: '{PatientId:"BH0012"}',
    contentType: "application/json,utf=charset-8",
    datatype: "JSON",
     success: function (response) {
//response= www.bts.abcd.com/ReportPdf/BH00118051710501_1_1.pdf
//Code for downloading the file
                }
            });
```

`
Different methods to achieve the same result will also be appreciated.

Comment: You can force a file for download instead of displaying via the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes i want to download the file from its path only. How do i force the file to download, i working code would be great.

Comment: By adding this line ( `AddType application/octet-stream .pdf` ) to the `.htaccess` file, you can force pdf files for download instead of displaying. Do you know how to edit the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @kavian-k, Not sure what exactly `.htaccess` is? Could you please share me some working code for this or any link to further see how this approach can solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: See this: [Forcing a file to download in a browser via htaccess](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/force-download-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways that were already mentioned would be by appending an invisible `<iframe>` and appending a `URL` in JS but there will be some security errors that will creep up.

---

In my method below, I have used `Axios.js` to allow me to safely download the file which also includes `Promises`.

---

> Axios.JS CDN: `<script
>   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>`

**JS**

---

```
function DownloadFromUrl(url, mime) {
  axios({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', // important
  }).then((response) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.' + mime);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  });
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Reporting/ReportAPI",
  data: '{PatientId:"BH0012"}',
  contentType: "application/json,utf=charset-8",
  datatype: "JSON",
  success: function(response) {
    // Response = URL
    // Mime     = File Type - pdf, jpeg, png, bmp, exe, js...
    DownloadFromUrl(response, "pdf");
  }
});
```

---

Make sure to wrap the `MIME` parameter as a string, or change the code above to validate the `MIME Type`

Here's JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5mnethL1/2/

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Nicely explained and demonstrated :).

Comment: @Vinod no problem! Hopefully, you'll find this code more reusable in the future, this was just a quick mockup.

Answer (score -1):

"winodw.location.href" cannot work in the ajax block. you can create a element, then click this.